# How do you implement ctime in C to store into a character buffer?

Tags: c

If you use `printf` such as:

```
printf("Time as a basic string = %s", ctime(&seconds));
```

The output would be:

```
Wed, 28 Oct 2009 11:35:37
```

How do I store this output that `ctime` generates so that:

```
char result[80] = ctime(&seconds);
```

Whatever I try just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The best way is probably to *pass the array as a parameter*, together with its length (because the array is adjusted to a pointer to its first element when passed and loses its size information). The function can then write into the provided buffer. Array assignment in the fashion you tried is generally not possible in C (one would need to strcpy()).

Comment: In case you want to *use* an existing `ctime()` (as opposed to implementing an equivalent), strcpy is indeed the answer if you have more calls to ctime later. If you have only one call, store the returned pointer in a pointer variable: `char *T0 = ctime(&seconds);` will do. `ctime()` has its own memory which will not go away.

Comment: `char result[80]; strcpy(result, ctime(&seconds));`?

Comment: You might want to try `strftime`, although before you can call it you have to have converted your time value into a `struct tm` by calling `localtime` or `gmtime` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy` as already proposed by multiple comments (hence this being a community wiki — it's not truthfully *my* answer) is correct for the use case given; also consider switching your array `result` to a pointer and using `strdup` to avoid having to make an assumption about string length at the cost of being responsible for a later `free`. So:

```
char result[80]; 
strcpy(result, ctime(&seconds));
```

Or:

```
char *result = strdup(ctime(&seconds));

... when you're done using result: ...
free(result);
```

Comment: While technically correct, the weakness is that many `ctime()` implementations still rely on a `static` buffer that has not been made thread local. Consequently, reentrant versions of APIs should be preferred over non-reentrant versions.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`ctime_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime_r) instead of `ctime`.

```
char result[80];
ctime_r(&seconds, result);
```

Comment: My understanding was different and, as jxh points out above, this solution is threadsafe unlike calls to vanilla `ctime`. So votes from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format,...);`.

By it, you can format your string. For example,

```
snprintf(result, MAX, "Time as a basic string = %s", ctime(&seconds));
```

and it will copy the string `"Time as a basic string = Wed, 28 Oct 2009 11:35:37"` into the result character array. You can add any string along with string returned by `ctime(&seconds)` using `snprintf()`.

Someone has mentioned an alternate way of copying a string. For that, you  need to declare result as a pointer to character and use `strdup()`. You can also use it but i wouldn't prefer it if your code is being written for Embedded Device due to dynamic memory allocation.